# Unable to login and use admin magento 1.9

Tags: magento, url, radix, magento-1.9.1

I changed admin base url now css and admin links do not work, i can login but nothing else works after that.

can anyone help?

I have tried to change admin url, i can atleast access the login page but apart from that nothing works.

Comment: remove all files inside `magento/var/cache/` and remove all cookies.

Comment: remove magento cache and clear browser cache and then check.